# How much does it cost to repair a water damaged floor of bathroom in Germany?

Tags: germany, rental, housing

I don't know whether it's right place to ask this question, but I'm in trouble to find an advise anywhere. Recently I have moved to Germany for work reason and I rented an apartment in Wuppertal. Unfortunately I damaged the filter in the shower room and didn't notice it and the water goes down and damaged the floor for almost 3 days, now my landlord ask me to pay for repair and she is telling that it could cost around 8000 Euros.

Could anyone please tell me that it's a reasonable amount for the damage ? Also is there anyway I can get help for this ? Unfortunately I don't have liability insurance.

Please find the images for your reference. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid nobody here can answer that. Your best bet is to actually get a craftsman yourself and ask them what they would charge to repair it. If it's significantly less, confront your landlord with it.

Comment: You might try asking on https://diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you asked her to get that estimate in writing from the tradesperson, broken down into costs? She should probably also get several quotes. Are you actually liable for the damage - what are your rental terms? Doesn’t the landlord have insurance to cover the damage?

Comment: Problem is not just the floor of your bathroom, but the ceiling etc in the bathroom below yours.

Comment: @Traveller yes I asked her for estimate report and she ll provide it on this week but she is telling that it definitely comes above 6000 Euros. I have removed the screws of shower room filter to clean it (that's the stupid mistake I did as I'm very new to this place and am not aware of this consequences) and the water gets leaked because of that. It's not a single house, its an apartment handled by a company. So I don't know wether they have insured this or not.

Comment: @Vencat Check the terms of your rental agreement regarding accidental damage to see exactly what you’re liable for. If you are liable and you don’t have the funds available, try asking if you can pay by instalments. Try contacting your local tenants’ association for advice https://www.iamexpat.de/housing/rentals-germany/rental-contracts-housing-rights

Comment: I had some water damage in my bathroom, which my insurance had to pay for. The damage in the bathroom was less than £50. The water went into my living room, destroyed the wall paper and the flooring, which resulted in a few thousand pounds worth of wooden flooring, a few hundred pound for wall paper, and for all the work, and for hiring three dehumidifiers that were on for a week. Most of the cost will not be to fix your bathroom. The damage is below your bathroom.